# Unlisted directory discovery of a web server without using bruteforce attacks

Tags: webserver, brute-force, file-access, fuzzing

Some creator I support on SubscribeStar hosts their files on a dedicated AWS web storage server of theirs and the names are easily accessible and sometimes guessable without any kind of security or authentication. I got curious to see what else is on there and found out that using something like a directory buster would essentially guess everything, but the wordlist would take a long time to go through, possibly eat up more CPU runtime and space than I can afford, and is really noisy, which could lead to it being seen as some kind of DoS attack, which I don't want to cause.

Then that got me wondering if there is some kind of way I can discover unlisted files without having to invoke bruteforce methods; it's purely for educational purposes as I'm interested in learning the practice and methods this person uses to create their content, and about potentially finding bug bounties. No ill will is intended, I merely just wish to satisfy my curiosity without causing undue harm.

Answer (score 0):

Without bruteforcing, you need to gain access to a pre-existing list or gain access to the system to be able to discover possible assets.

In "the olden days" you could try to get to the parent directory, which would list all sub-directories. While this trick still works on older, misconfigured webservers (I found one last month), this directory listing trick tends to not be possible on cloud storage, like AWS.

What is more possible on AWS is a misconfigured permission on the S3 bucket, which gives you access to directories to be able to bruteforce enumerate.

The other option, which sometimes works, is an old-fashioned google dork, where you get a pre-existing list of the things that Google has been able to find or that other people access often.